# Setting my plotly marker size as a variable is not working when using frame (i.e. animated graph)

Tags: r, graph, r-plotly

I'm struggling to get my marker size to work as expected when I'm using it in an animated graph. Using a data set like below, I'd want the marker in column 1 to increase in size, then decrease; the marker in 2 to decrease in size, then increase; etc.:

```
data <- data.frame(xaxis = rep(as.character(c(1:5)), each = 10), 
                   yaxis = rep(c(1:5,5:1), 5), 
                   size = c(
                       c(1:5,5:1),
                       c(5:1,1:5),
                       c(1:10),
                       c(10:1),
                       rep(c(1,10), 5)
                   ),
                    frame = c(1:10)
                   )
```

Frustratingly, when I run just one marker (i.e. data is `data[data$xaxis == 1, ]`), everything works as expected; but by the time show all 5 markers, the sizes go haywire.

How can I get better control of my marker size?

Example plot:

```
plot_ly(
    data = data,
    x = ~xaxis,
    y = ~yaxis,
    frame = ~frame,
    type = 'scatter',
    marker = list(size = ~size*10),
    mode = 'markers'
)
```

Comment: This seems to be working for me with all points active

Comment: Sorry - I just saw an error in my example code; I've now added in all of the markers.

Comment: I made that adjustment when I tested it.  Are your packages updated? R?

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/1856) you can find the related GitHub issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why, but it works fine, once you order your data according to your frames:

```
library(plotly)

data <- data.frame(xaxis = rep(as.character(c(1:5)), each = 10), 
                   yaxis = rep(c(1:5,5:1), 5), 
                   size = c(
                     c(1:5,5:1),
                     c(5:1,1:5),
                     c(1:10),
                     c(10:1),
                     rep(c(1,10), 5)
                   ),
                   frame = c(1:10)
)

data <- data[order(data$frame),]

plot_ly(
  data = data,
  x = ~xaxis,
  y = ~yaxis,
  frame = ~frame,
  type = 'scatter',
  marker = list(size = ~size*10),
  mode = 'markers'
)
```

[image: result]

You might want to [file an issue](https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues) regarding this.

Comment: Thank you!! I've no idea how you identified this - but really appreciate it. I'll create and issue.

Comment: I saw, that in your example the sizes where simply "played" from top to bottom of your data.frame (independent from the frames) - so I tried to reorder. Glad I could help!